# Dynamic check whether class is present or not

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following classes applied to a span tag :

c1

i want to check whether c_2 (any particular class) is applied or not using js

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) JavaScript library and things like these are all already implemented in there. You could use the [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method to check whether an element has a css class